# Where can I find examples of tasks given by the warlock patron?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, warlock

As a DM, I always have trouble about warlocks' patrons. I can never find any good tasks or services to ask of my players (and they can't find any either.) So I just go with "When I'll ask you something, you will do it" which feels bad.

Is there a place on the internet where I can find examples  of tasks given by the warlock patron? (Because I think asking directly here would be a "question closed because opinion based" scenario)

Comment: I like this question, and can sympathise, but I'm not sure the stack is the best place for this question. This seems like a "shopping question", and may be a better fit on a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/35259) or the RPG.SE chat.

Answer (score 3):

## This is DM territory.

A close examination of the [Otherworldly Patrons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#OtherworldlyPatrons) section of the [Warlock class](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#WarlockClassDetails) can give you plenty of inspiration.

For example, a part of [The Archfey](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#TheArchfey) description explains that some possible tasks

> might involve a striving for greater magical power or the settling of
> age-old grudges

This could translate into the Warlock needing to hunt down specific magic items for their patron, or require them to offer a sacrifice of a current magic item. This patron might require the Warlock to settle an old grudge by killing/embarrassing/defeating some opposed Fey creature.

Ultimately, it's up to the DM to *examine* the patron, *determine* what it's goals are, and then *work the accomplishment of those goals into the campaign*. Yes, it's a little bit of work, but creating a compelling story for your players to work their way through IS your job!

Comment: I know this is my job, if it wasn't, that would have been my players that had to ask this question, not me

Comment: @Rorp I'm not saying you're doing it poorly. A lesser DM wouldn't take the time to do what you're doing. They'd just throw a bunch of modules at their players and never worry about actually involving them in a story like you are. I think you're 100% on the right track.